# Is the antecedent of a relative pronoun governed solely by proximity?

Tags: that

*There is a group of people that is very smart.*

My question is: Does the word *that* always modify the closest noun phrase?
If so, the word *students* is modified by *that* here, and the correct version would be:

*There is a group of people that are very smart.*

If I am right, another question: Is Trump wrong in terms of grammar?

He said: *There is a group of people that is very sick*

https://youtu.be/m5YDIWXzRaI?t=16s

Answer (score 2):

The antecedent of a relative pronoun may depend on things other than proximity. Number, for instance. If I say

> The Rockies is a range of mountains that **is** very large

I'm talking about a group of mountains, and that grouping covers a large area. The mountains themselves may be large or not. *Range* is singular, and so is the verb (*is*) of the relative clause. Thus the antecedent of *that* must be *range*. On the other hand, if I say

> The Rockies is a range of mountains that **are** very large

I'm talking about a group of sizable mountains. The plural verb *are* must agree with the plural noun *mountains*, so the antecedent of *that* must be *mountains*.

Calling a group of sick people a *sick group* is acceptable, certainly in extemporaneous speech, so I wouldn't call Trump's statement ungrammatical.

Comment: +1 for making the title easier to improve (and a clearer example) (and the point about the transferred epithet). I find it almost impossible to believe that this hasn't been asked before. ... ... ... Ah, got it.

Comment: A further complication involves the grammaticality of the predicative version when using transferred epithets. 'I had a quiet pint' is fine, but 'I had a pint that was quiet' very iffy.

Answer (score 0):

'That' does not have to always refer to the closest noun. In fact, in the sentence

> There is a group of people that is very smart,

that refers to the 'group' of people, not to the noun 'people'. So, the usage of 'is' is appropriate in the sentence.

The answer to your second question is, evidently, no. Trump is grammatically correct in this sentence.

Actually, this question is about restrictive clauses and non-restrictive clauses. For referring to multiple objects, you should use 'which'. For details, you must have a look [here](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/which.html).

Comment: This interpretation with this example (contrast deadrat's) has to involve some figure of speech, as it has to be the people who are smart.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you are correct to observe that I am qualifying the 'group' as smart. This interpretation concurs with deadrat's first example where the 'range' is qualified as large.

Comment: But 'large range' means 'a range that is large' not 'a range whose mountains are large' whereas 'smart group' must mean 'a group whose members are large'. Not incorrect, but a subtlety that deadrat picks up on.

Comment: +1 for explaining the dissimilitude between the two usages.